# FadeOut without click

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my spelling game, when a word is complete it fades away in the grid. When a set amount of words are complete (in this case 3) the whole grid fades to reveal the image behind. The problem I have at the moment is when I complete the third word, nothing happens until I click the mouse again.

I need it so as soon as that word is complete the script runs without a click of the mouse.

Here is the piece of code that triggers the fadeOut...

```
$('.drag').on('click', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
if(animation) return;
animation = true;
setTimeout(function(){animation = false;},500);
var target = $('.drop-box.spellword:not(.occupied):first');
var targetPos = target.position();
var currentPos = $(this).offset();
var b = $(this);

if (target.length) {
    target.addClass("occupied");
    $(".minibutton").prop("disabled", true);
    b.clone().addClass(
    b.data("letter") == target.data("letter") ? "wordglow3" : "wordglow").appendTo("table").css({
        background: "transparent",
        position: "absolute",
        top: currentPos.top,
        left: currentPos.left
    }).animate({
        top: targetPos.top,
        left: targetPos.left
    }, "slow", function() {
        $(this).css({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }).appendTo(target);
        if (!$('.drop-box.spellword:not(.occupied)').length) {
            var wordIsCorrect = 0;
            $('.drop-box.spellword').each(function() {
                if ($(this).attr("data-letter") == $(this).find("div").attr("data-letter")) {
                    wordIsCorrect++;
                }
            });
            console.log(wordIsCorrect);
            console.log($('.drop-box.spellword').length);
            if ($('.drop-box.spellword').length == wordIsCorrect) {

                $('.drop-box.spellword').addClass('wordglow2');
                $(right).val('Well Done!');
                $(right).show();
                audioS.play();
                $('.counter').html(completeWords + '/6').show();
                $(wrong).hide();
                $('.minibutton').prop('disabled', false);

            } else {

                $('.drop-box.spellword').addClass("wordglow4").css('color', 'transparent');
                $(wrong).val('Try Again');
                $('.minibutton').prop('disabled');
                $(wrong).show();
                audioF.play();
                $('.counter').html(completeWords + '/6').show();
                $(right).hide();
                //$('.minibutton').prop('disabled', true);

                $('.drop-box.spellword')
                    .animate({ 'opacity': 1 }, 2000, function()
                             {
                                $(this)
                                    .removeClass('wordglow4')
                                    .removeClass('occupied')
                                    .html('')
                                    });
            }


        }
    });

}


var completeLetters = $('.wordglow2').length;
var completeWords = (completeLetters / 3);
$('.counter').html(completeWords + '/6');

if (completeWords == 3) {
    $('table').fadeOut(2000);
}

var incompleteWords = $('.spellword').hasClass('.wordglow4').length;
if (incompleteWords == 3) {
    $('.minibutton').prop('disabled', false);
}
```

});

THANKS!!

Comment: People at SO are writing your entire game ;)

Comment: What event is that piece of code being run under? Is there more code that you haven't posted?

Comment: There's the whole event @Rory McCrossan

Comment: @sMilbz is this entire scenario triggered by a mouse click?

Comment: @sMilbz I have added a suggestion for you. Take a look to see whether it works.

Comment: @Konstantin Dinev it doesnt sorry

Comment: can we see it live somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your level completion test:

```
if (completeWords == 1) {
    $('table').fadeOut(2000);
}
```

is hit before the clicked letter is added.. Your code is too messy for me to understand, but I suggest you move this test into the branch where you test for completed word, which works fine.

```
if ($('.drop-box.spellword').length == wordIsCorrect) {

  $('.drop-box.spellword').addClass('wordglow2');
  $(right).val('Well Done!');

  // move the above test here
}
```